# Redisson client setnx

Tags: java, caching, redis, redisson

I am using Redisson as java redis library whats the corresponding function in redisson for setnx(conditional set a key's value and get result as 1 if value is set). I am using redis in clustered mode (sharded cluster).

Thanks

Comment: What is the problem?

Answer (score 6):

Use RBucket object:

```
RBucket<Object> bucket = redisson.getBucket("myObject");
bucket.trySet(object); // return true if object wasn't set before
```

Also you can refer to https://github.com/redisson/redisson/wiki/11.-Redis-commands-mapping for mapping of other Redis commands.